# Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, nspredicate

So I'm converting this line of code

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(TidyFeed * _Nonnull item, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
        return ![item.feedEntryId isEqualToString:feedEntryId];
    }];
```

to swift code

```
var predicate = NSPredicate { (item: TidyFeed, bindings: NSDictionary) in
        return !(item.feedEntryId == feedEntryId)
    }
```

but I get this error

> Cannot convert value of type '(TidyFeed, NSDictionary) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(AnyObject, [String : AnyObject]?) -> Bool'

has anyone encounter this error when using blocks?

**Additional Info**

Swift code

```
  apiClient.dismissFeed(feedEntryId, completion: {(responseObject: AnyObject, error: NSError) -> Void in

    })
```

Error

> Cannot convert value of type '(AnyObject, NSError) -> Void' to expected argument type 'AFAPIOperationCompletionBlock!'

and here's the completion block code of **AFAPIOperationCompletionBlock**

```
- (void) completion:(id)responseObject error:(NSError *)error
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, the first parameter `id evaluatedBlock` of the closure
can be substituted by any object pointer, like `TidyFeed *`, and that
is a known method to avoid additional pointer conversion if you know for sure that the evaluated objects are in fact of that type.

Swift however does not allow this, and you have to cast the pointer
inside the block:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate { (item: AnyObject, _) -> Bool in
    return (item as! TidyFeed).feedEntryId != feedEntryId
}
```

This will crash if the block is called with an object which is not
of the type `TidyFeed`. A safe version is

```
let predicate = NSPredicate { (item: AnyObject, _) -> Bool in
    if let feed = item as? TidyFeed {
        return feed.feedEntryId != feedEntryId
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

with an optional cast. This can be written more compactly as:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate { (item: AnyObject, _) -> Bool in
    return (item as? TidyFeed)?.feedEntryId != feedEntryId
}
```

Note also how you can use the wildcard pattern `_` for the unused
`bindings` parameter.